# Cannot Access Samba Share on windows 10

Tags: centos, samba

I cannot seem to share the folders in Centos 7 on windows 10.

I have activated the SMB features (both client and server) in windows 10 and configured the smb.conf file in centos 7 to allow read and write permissions to all users.

I have configured three share options in the configuration file; share, storage and test, i am able to access the share option but it has corrupted options with the database (access) sitting on the server. Something wrong the file permissions, files are getting corrupted as the users edit/save a file.

here's my smb.conf file:

```
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.

[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user
    netbios name = files
    idmap config * : backend =tbd

    passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = No
    inherit acls = Yes
    read only = No
    valid users = %S %D%w%S

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = @printadmin root
    force group = @printadmin
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775

[Share]
    oplocks = no
    writeable = yes
    locking = no
    path = /srv/samba/files/share
    force user = nobody
    comment = Temp file-server
    create mode = 777
    public = yes
    browsable = yes
    directory mode = 777    


[Storage]
    oplocks = no
    writeable = yes
    locking = no
    path = /mnt/b70a0058-040e-4815-8bcf-2b5bc5ce6f03/Share
    force user = nobody
    comment = File Server Share
    create mode = 777
    public = yes
    browsable = yes
    directory mode = 777    

[test]
    guest account = admin
    oplocks = no
    writeable = yes
    locking = no
    path = /mnt/b70a0058-040e-4815-8bcf-2b5bc5ce6f03/test
    force user = admin
    comment = Temp file-server
    public = yes
    browsable = yes
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777
```

Comment: I have managed to fix my error.

the samba user did not belong to the samba group



also added the user as admin user to have rwx access to the files